# How can I transfer a wordpress project from one server into another server sub-directory?

Tags: wordpress

I have an installed worpress project which is working on `server_A`. To transfer it, I created a zip file of all files that are in the public_html of `serevr_A`. and uploaded it in the `server_B/mag/`.

Also I've exported/imported the database in the new server and modified new credentials in the `wp-config.php`. Noted that, the database connection works well in the new server.

The problem is, when I open the project on the new server `http://example.com/mag` through the browser, it says:

> Page not found

I guess it's because of that sub-directory in the new server named `mag` *(because the installed wordpress project been on the root of the old server)*.

Anyway, do you know how can I make it working?

---

The content of `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

I use Laravel framework and this is the content of the main (root) `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in sub-folder?

Comment: yes, added in my question.

Answer (score 1):

In .htacess you need to do following change add your folder name in rewrite base and rule. Below will work for you.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mag/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /mag/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Comment: I have setup 2 wordpress one in parent and another as a child and add rule as per above its working fine, can you please check main domain .htaccess and and can you please share that one as well ?

Comment: The main `.htaccess` added in my question.

Comment: I modified `siteurl` and `home` in the `wp_options` table of database and it works now .. (noted that your solution is part of the answer and without doing that it will not work, so upvote)

Comment: Thank you Martin :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to change the websites url in your wordpress database via the wp_options table.

You'll see two fields ralating to those shown in the WP admin settings, edit these accordingly.

Comment: In which table?

Comment: Ok I did it in the `wp_options` table and it works as well. Thank you. upvote